# Number of connected components of the centre of a Levi subgroup

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, algebraic-groups

Let $G$ be a connected complex semisimple algebraic group and $T\subset B\subset G$ a choice of maximal torus and Borel subgroup. Let $\Phi$ be the root system and $\Pi\subset\Phi$ the set of simple roots associated to $T$ and $B$. For each subset $I\subseteq\Pi$, let $L_I\subseteq G$ be the Levi factor of the standard parabolic subgroup associated to $I$.

> **Question.** Is there a combinatorial description of the number of connected components of the centre of $L_I$?

A combinatorial description could be an explicit formula (e.g. in terms of $Z_G$ and $I$) or a way to compute it for any given $G$ and $I$.

Comment: In other words, we're looking for the size of the torsion part of $X^*(T)/\mathbb Z I$.  (That's assuming that you're normalising things so that $L_\emptyset = T$.)